# Echo date once if same

Tags: php

I have this code to display date and time:

```
while ($re = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

       $datetime = new DateTime($re["start"]);
       $time = $dateTime->format('H:i');

       echo "<p>", $dateTime->format('l, d.m.y'), "</p>";
       echo "<a href='reservation.php'>$time</a>";

}
```

Now I get for same day that has more times (hours:minutes) new result with day and date but i need to list all times under one day, date.

This is how it looks now:

Monday, 07.07.2014.
10:30
Monday, 07.07.2014.
12:30

And I need it like this:

Monday, 07.07.2014.
10:30 12:30

Comment: the process is this, keep track of $day echo it once then not again untill it changes

Comment: @Dagon hello again :) maybe he could group by date in the sql query?

Comment: what query would that be?

Comment: @Dagon the one which results in `$result2` I realize that code is not posted here, I was just questioning the feasibility of the approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed your query is ordered by date you can use a variable to track date changes:

```
$last_day="";
while ($re = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
       $datetime = $re["start"];
       $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
       $date = date('l, d.m.Y.',$datetime);  // Why use 2 vars?
       if($date != $last_day) {
            $last_day = $date;
            echo "<p>$date</p>";
       }
       $time = date('H:i',$datetime);

       echo "<a href='reservation.php'>$time</a>";
}
```

Probably you want to put also $time into link as parameter.